# Google Sheets sum after last criteria cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can't find anything for this, and my brain keeps going to a object oriented solutions which as far as i know cant be implemented here.

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 |
| -3 | 10 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 5 | 13 |

I have a google sheet with the following data, i want to figure out how to get the sum of column b values, but only for those values after the last known negative number in column a.

IE: the formula should give me a sum of 11 and 13 = 24 since only 4 and 5 are the positives number after the last known negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with [Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions) making a custom function.

The function is very basic.

```
function sumFromLastNeg(data) {
  var run_sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] >= 0){
      run_sum += data[i][1];
    }
    else if (data[i][0] < 0){
      run_sum = 0;
    }
  }
  return run_sum;
}
```

The functions is called like so `=sumFromLastNeg(A1:B)`

My original thinking was i would not be able to do this, but through my looking for solutions found scripting in google sheets.

Hope this helps people!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(LOOKUP(9^9,IF(A1:A<0,A1:A)),A1:A,0)+1&":B")))`

**Looking at this formula piecemeal:**

1. Lookup for the last negative number in the range:
   `LOOKUP(9^9,IF(A1:A<0,A1:A))`
2. Find its position in the range and add 1 to get next position: `MATCH(<formula in step 1>),A1:A,0)+1`
3. Build the sum range using indirect. `SUM(INDIRECT("B"&<formula in step 2>&":B"))`
4. Encapsulate in `ARRAYFORMULA` to retrieve the result.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: So this work great, but there is a problem when you have multiple negative numbers.


If i have one more row with `-6 ,10`, it shows 0; which is correct

If i add another row `7,13`, it shows 13, which is also correct.

however if i change row 6 from `-6,10` to `-3,10`, it shows 47, which is not right. the right value would still be 13.

Comment: BTW, i did technically solve this, but making a custom function using "Apps Scripts".

But that solution is more script based, and required some JS coding.